# ROC curve - model performace error

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, roc

I am trying to plot a ROC curve to show my model performance. The model is fitted using the `randomForest` package

```
prediction <- predict(fit, test, type="prob")
pred <- prediction(test$prediction, test$flag_cross_over )
pred2 <- prediction(abs(test$prediction + 
                    rnorm(length(test$prediction), 0, 0.1)), flag_cross_over)
perf <- performance( pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
perf2 <- performance(pred2, "tpr", "fpr")
plot( perf, colorize = TRUE)
plot(perf2, add = TRUE, colorize = TRUE)
```

So using the test data I am trying to check the model performance. So the prediction column holds the predictions made and the `flag_cross_over` is the labels for the model.

The error is saying:

> Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.
>   .

the prediction dimensions is 410 2
the labels dim is 410 1

I am unsure why the prediction has one more value in the dimensions

Comment: the predictions are binary as too the labels, yes and no answer. I am not sure if this is my problem

Comment: As far as I can see, your problem has nothing to do with a ROC curve.

Comment: ok, can you expand on that please? What is the problem? @pascal

Comment: Your use of `prediction` function.

Comment: sorry, i have added another line of code i missed out, is this using the predict function properly? @pascal

Comment: According to the help page, `labels` must have the same dimensions as `predictions`.

Comment: yeah for some reason when using the "prob" function provides a two dimension matrix, with the probability continous numbers. Although when using the response function a list is provided with 1 and 0 binary numbers @pascal